# I am attempting to control two stepper motors by using serial input. My code works, however I have to press the new directional command multiple times

Tags: arduino-uno, stepper-motor

I am using two 28BYJ-48 stepper motors with two motor drivers that they come with. (I don't know the name of them.)

Here is my code:

```
/*
 * Code to control two stepper motors simultaneously using the stepper library function calls
 * This code has functions which make calls to initiate one step from each of the two motors at a time
 * therefore each motor takes it in turn to step with the end result of them both running together
 * the variable 'lastCall' allows for a continuous input to keep the steppers running if there is no serial input
 * Written by Gabriel Adams  - March 2023 - 
 */
#include <Stepper.h>

//definitions for each command to be recieved via serial port
#define COMMAND_LEFT 'a'
#define COMMAND_RIGHT 'd'
#define COMMAND_FORWARD 'w'
#define COMMAND_BACK 's'
#define COMMAND_STOP ' '

//Number of steps per internal motor revolution
const float STEPS_PER_REV = 32;

//Amount of gear reduction
const float GEAR_RED = 64;

//Number of steps per geared output rotation
const float STEPS_PER_OUT_REV = STEPS_PER_REV * GEAR_RED;

//enter the steps per rev for your motors here
int stepsInRev = STEPS_PER_OUT_REV ;

//this sets the value for the for loops and therefore sets the amount of steps in each call
int num_of_steps = 1;
// setup pins for each driver motor1 ~ IN1, IN2, IN3, IN4; motor2 ~ IN1, IN2, IN3, IN4
Stepper myStepper1(STEPS_PER_OUT_REV, 4, 6, 5, 7);
Stepper myStepper2(STEPS_PER_OUT_REV, 8, 10, 9, 11);
// variable to store the last call to the serial port
char lastCall = ' ';

//I had prototyped all of the functions here, but for some reason the Arduino IDE didn't like it
//so they are coded out until I an figure out why
//void forwardStep();
//void backwardStep();
//void leftStep();
//void rightStep();
//void allStop();

//to move the motors forward
void forwardStep(int steps){
  Serial.println("forward");
  // step one step each forward
  myStepper1.step(1);
  myStepper2.step(1);
  delay(10);
}

// to move the motors back
void backwardStep(int steps){
  Serial.println("backward");
  // step one step each backward
  myStepper1.step(-1);
  myStepper2.step(-1);
  delay(10);
}
 

// to move the motors in opposite directions (left)
void leftStep(int steps){
  Serial.println("left");
 // step one step each left
  myStepper1.step(1);
  myStepper2.step(-1);
  delay(10);
}


// to move the motors in opposite directions (right)
void rightStep(int steps){
  Serial.println("right");
  // step one step each right
  myStepper1.step(-1);
  myStepper2.step(1);
  delay(10); 
}

// to power down the motor drivers and stop the motors
void allStop(){
  Serial.println("stop");
  // steppers stop
  PORTD = B00000000; //sets all of the pins 0 to 7 as LOW to power off stepper1
  PORTB = B00000000; //sets all of the pins 8 to 13 as LOW to power off stepper2
}
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);//start the bluetooth serial port - send and recieve at 9600 baud
  // set the speed at 60 rpm:
  myStepper1.setSpeed(700);
  myStepper2.setSpeed(700);
}

void loop() {
//check to see if there is serial communication and if so read the data
if(Serial.available()) {
char data = (char)Serial.read();
// switch to set the char via serial to a command
switch(data) {
  case COMMAND_FORWARD:
    forwardStep(num_of_steps);
    break; 
  case COMMAND_BACK:
    backwardStep(num_of_steps);
    break;
  case COMMAND_LEFT:
    leftStep(num_of_steps);
    break;
  case COMMAND_RIGHT:
    rightStep(num_of_steps);
    break;
  case COMMAND_STOP:
    allStop();
    break;
}
// set the 'lastCall' variable to the last call from the serial
lastCall = data;
}

char data = lastCall;

Loop(lastCall);
Serial.read();

}

void Loop(char x){
switch(lastCall) {
  case COMMAND_FORWARD:
    forwardStep(num_of_steps);
    break; 
  case COMMAND_BACK:
    backwardStep(num_of_steps);
    break;
  case COMMAND_LEFT:
    leftStep(num_of_steps);
    break;
  case COMMAND_RIGHT:
    rightStep(num_of_steps);
    break;
  case COMMAND_STOP:
    allStop();
    break;
}
return lastCall; 

(char)Serial.read();
}
```

Comment: Why are you doing these two `Serial.read()`s without using the result outside of your serial code? If your data arrives right before that, it will just be discarded.

Comment: I am still in the learning process of object-oriented coding. I was thinking the Serial.read() command would ensure more immediate reads of serial inputs. How would I better assess this? As in, instead of how at the moment it won't immediately change direction when I give a new command, how do I ulitize the Serial.read() command to quickly move to a new loop.

Comment: Seems you have a strange understanding of function parameters, which are not used by the functions. BTW: function prototyping is done by the IDE for you, but if you do it yourself, do it right: parameters should fit.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that you are reading from the Serial buffer without using the data. There are three places in your code, where you use `Serial.read();`:

1. You use in in the block with your serial code and you set `lastCall` accordingly. This is ok.
2. Then you use it at the end of `void loop()`, but you don't assign the value to anything.
3. And you use it at the end of your own `Loop()` function, again without assigning the value to anything.

Short explanation how `Serial` works: The Uno has hardware to handle Serial communication in the background via interrupts. The data arrives at the Uno and gets automatically (in the background) places in the internal buffer of the `Serial` object. The call to `Serial.read()` removes the oldest byte from the buffer (so that you get the bytes in order of arrival) and returns it. If there is no new data byte available it will return `-1`.

So when you just use `Serial.read()` without assigning the value to anything, you are basically throwing away data bytes from the Serial buffer.

> I was thinking the Serial.read() command would ensure more immediate reads of serial inputs.

Reading the data from the buffer is not enough. You actually have to do something with it. Otherwise you are just reading without reacting. So please remove the two calls to `Serial.read()`, only leaving the the one in your `if(Serial.available())` block.

> how at the moment it won't immediately change direction when I give a new command, how do I utilize the Serial.read() command to quickly move to a new loop?

You should remove all the calls to `delay()`. Currently your code spends the most time in these delays, doing nothing. Instead you can use the non-blocking coding style from the `BlinkWithoutDelay` example, that comes with the Arduino IDE. It uses `millis()` as a time keeper, only executing the code (blinking an LED in the example; doing a step in your code) when it is time to do  so. There are many tutorials about that online.

If you want you can even go further and switch to the `AccelStepper` library, which is more capable than the standard `Stepper` library. It lets you set the speed and acceleration and then you simply run the motor by executing the `run()` method often enough. No need for your own timing of steps then, because the library is handling that. Though this will be a bigger change to your code.